# 興味を持ってきている versus 興味がある

Tags: word-choice

> 1. 子供の頃からずっとロボットに興味**を持って来ています**。
> 2. 子供の頃からずっとロボットに興味**があります**。

Which sentence sounds more natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence 2 is better. Using both 来る (describes change over time) and いる (describes continuation of state) at the same time sounds odd to me. But you can safely say:

> - 子供の頃からずっとロボットに興味を持って来ました。
> - 子供の頃からずっとロボットに興味を持っています。